# Creating multiple while loops for one array in php and mysqli

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, while-loop

so I am trying to create a list that will display all users who are part of a region. For this I am trying to use a while loop where it will display all the names. See code below:

```
<h2>Region 2:</h2>
<?php 

          //REGION 2:
          $result = mysqli_query($ExampleDB,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE region=2 ORDER BY user DESC");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
              echo "</br>Position 2: ";
              if ($row['position']==2){
              echo"".$row['fname']." ".$row['sname'].", ";
              }
              echo "</br>Position 3: ";
              if ($row['position']==3){
              echo"".$row['fname']." ".$row['sname'].", ";
              }
              }
          mysqli_close($dbConnection);
          }
?>
```

The only problem with this is that then it will obviously also echo the "Position 2" and "Position 3" for every user... Any suggestions on how to split up the two positions so that the while loop occurs after the echo? I also tried to split up the while loops like this, but then none of the names showed up:

```
              $result = mysqli_query($ExampleDB,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE region=2 ORDER BY user DESC");

              echo "</br></br>Position 2: ";
              while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                  if ($row2['position']==2){
                  echo"".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['sname']." ".$row2['user'].", ";
                  }
              }           
              echo "</br></br>Position 3: ";
              while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                  if ($row3['position']==3){
                  echo"".$row['fname']." ".$row['sname'].", ";
                  }
              }
```

I also tried it with keeping them all as $row and that didn't produce any names either. How can I split up the while loops? Or is there a better way to echo the specific names in the array after the Position 2,3 headers?

Comment: I notice you use `$row['position']==2` in your first example and `$row2['f_pos']==2` in your second. Not sure if this is a problem though.

Comment: oops was just simplifying the wording and forgot to change it on second. They are the same in my actual code. Fixed in edit

Comment: @user1066035 I have the same problem, have the problem solved by the answer given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($ExampleDB,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE region=2 ORDER BY user DESC");

echo "</br></br>Position 2: ";
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($row2['position']==2)
    {
         echo"".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['sname']." ".$row2['user'].", ";
    }
}   

$result = mysqli_query($ExampleDB,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE region=2 ORDER BY user DESC");

echo "</br></br>Position 3: ";
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     if ($row3['position']==3)
     {
        echo"".$row['fname']." ".$row['sname'].", ";
     }
}
```

This actually works fine if you query the statement again. After the first while loop fetch array gets to the end of the array. And performing fetch array returns nothing. Hence you have to query again.

Comment: May not be pretty but works for me. Cheers! Will select as an answer when possible :)

Comment: Well the pretty thing here can be put $result2=$result before first while loop and use $result2 in your second while loop. This can avoid querying again on mysql. Consider it if you have much BIGGER data. You can also reset the mysqli_fetch_array by using     mysql_data_seek( $result, 0 ); statement

Comment: I think he could also simply use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php `$result->data_seek(0);` to reset the pointer of result back to the beginning instead of doing mysqli_query again? Note sure myself, never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag after outputting the header the first time. This isn't ideal, but avoids having to rework your approach:

```
$pos_two_header = true;
$pos_three_header = true;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if ($row['position']==2){
            if($pos_two_header) {
                echo "</br>Position 2: ";
                $pos_two_header = false;
             }
            echo"".$row['fname']." ".$row['sname'].", ";
        }
        if ($row['position']==3){
            if($pos_three_header) {
                echo "</br>Position 2: ";
                $pos_three_header = false;
             }
            echo"".$row['fname']." ".$row['sname'].", ";
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jeroen's comment about using `data_seek` instead of running the query the second time, this will work but not quite as easy as simply seeking to the 0 index. It's much easier to handle this solution with PHP 5.4 where the result set is returned as Traversable. Like this:

```
$result = $ExampleDB->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE region=2 ORDER BY user DESC");

foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo "</br>Position 2: ";
        if ($row['position']==2){
            echo"".$row['fname']." ".$row['sname'].", ";
        }
    }

$result->field_seek(0);

foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo "</br>Position 3: ";
        if ($row['position']==3){
            echo"".$row['fname']." ".$row['sname'].", ";
        }
    }
```